# Which is more appropriate here?

Tags: formal-language

Context: I ordered something online and would like to return it as it is defective. The site has a 30 days return policy. 30 days will get over in a week and they have not arranged any pickup. Which one sounds more professional and appropriate?

> 30 days to return the product will get over soon.
>
> 30 day window to return the product will close in a week.
>
> 30 days to return the product are ending.

Comment: careful with uses like: get over. To get over something is an idiom. And isn't: to be over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply say

> The 30 day return period will end soon

As @Lambie points out "***get over***" has a differnt meaning

> 30 days to return the product will **be** over soon.